# I added a wp-query in front of my loop but it disables any pagination

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Showtime wordpress theme which builds a blog based on a single category.

I modified it and added a query_posts('cat='.$category_id.''.$temp.'&posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page')); in front of the loop to get multiple categories back.

However, this query disables pagination and makes every page the same posts.

I guess i would have to modify the orignal wp-query the theme uses? Where is it usually located as I cannot find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('cat='.$category_id.''.$temp.'&paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page')); // choose which category posts are shown
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
wp_reset_query();
```

After you loop on your query_posts